# Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" arguments(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have inherited this script from the previous developer and I am having trouble executing query.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
    $site = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/fulltest2"
    $listName = "Show Calendar"
    $user = "spadmin@site.onmicrosoft.com"   
    $pwd =ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force  

    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user,$pwd)
    $ctx.Credentials = $credentials
    $siteColl = $ctx.Web
    $ctx.Load($siteColl)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
    $ctx.Load($list)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried the exact same script on one of my site's and it worked(Replaced Site URL, List name, ID, Password).
Please make sure your Site URL, List name, ID, Password are correct. If MFA is enabled in your tenant make sure you are VPN'd in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke TLS 1.2

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Past the code line in the firs line of PS script.